# Edit a shortcut to run as administrator

Tags: windows, file-shortcut

I use Visual Studio, which I usually need to have running as Administrator - I've set the startup shortcut to run as admin by default. Every time there's a Visual Studio update, I have to manually

1. Right click the item in the "Start" menu
2. Choose Find Item Location
3. Right click the shortcut
4. Choose Properties
5. Click "Advanced"
6. Check the "Run as administrator" option

Is there any way to do this via a batch file, that I can run every time Visual Studio is updated? In other words, how can I edit a shortcut so that the "Run as administrator" option is selected?

Comment: Using the Windows Scripting Host this should be possible. Or using Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio updates replace the executable, but do not change its name.

You may create a shortcut to the executable yourself (not by the installation)
and mark it as "Run as administrator". This should not be affected
by Visual Studio updates.

You may also add your project as parameter on the call to the
Visual Studio executable, if you would like to create icons for
your projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this vbscript to create a shortcut with admin rights :

[Run_As_Admin_Create_Shortcut.vbs](https://pastebin.com/SdFQ8Exr)

---

```vbs
Option Explicit
Const Title = "Create a shortcut for the current vbscript or any other application with arguments using an array"
Call RunAsAdmin()

Create_Shortcut Array("Desktop","Recent","shell:Recent")

Create_Shortcut Array("Desktop","User profile","%userprofile%")

Create_Shortcut Array(_
    "Desktop",_
    "NetworkDiagnostics",_
    "%SystemRoot%\system32\msdt.exe",_
    "-skip TRUE -path %Windir%\diagnostics\system\networking -ep NetworkDiagnosticsPNI",_
    "%SystemRoot%\system32\msdt.exe,0",_
    "Network Diagnostics to fix connections problems",_
    "CTRL+ALT+D"_
)
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Create_Shortcut(rArgs) 
    Dim objShell,objShortCut,ObjShortcutPath,ShortcutName,ShortcutPath,ShortcutLocation
    Dim TargetPath,Arguments,IconLocation,Description,HotKey
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    If UBound(rArgs) > 1 Then
        ShortcutLocation       = cstr(rArgs(0))
        ShortcutPath           = objShell.SpecialFolders(ShortcutLocation)
        ShortcutName           = cstr(rArgs(1))
        Set objShortCut        = objShell.CreateShortcut(ShortcutPath & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk")
        TargetPath             = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(rArgs(2))
        objShortCut.TargetPath = TargetPath 
        If ShortcutPath = "" Then 
            MsgBox "Error The Shortcut Path Does Not Exsists On Your System."_
            ,vbCritical+vbSystemModal,Title
            wscript.quit(1)
        End If
    End If

    If UBound(rArgs) > 2 Then
        Arguments = cstr(rArgs(3))
        objShortCut.Arguments = Arguments
    End If

    If UBound(rArgs) > 3 Then
        IconLocation = cstr(rArgs(4))
        ObjShortCut.IconLocation = IconLocation
    End If

    If UBound(rArgs) > 4 Then
        Description = cstr(rArgs(5))
        ObjShortCut.Description = Description
    End If
    
    If UBound(rArgs) > 5 Then
        HotKey = cstr(rArgs(6))
        ObjShortCut.HotKey = HotKey
    End If
    objShortCut.Save
    On Error Resume Next
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ShowError() 
    Else 
        objShell.Popup "The Shortcut "& chr(34) & ShortcutName & chr(34) &" is created Successfully !"& vbcrlf &_
        "On " & chr(34) & ShortcutPath & chr(34),5,Title,vbInformation+vbSystemModal
    End If
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ShowError()
    ErrDetail = "Description : " & Err.Description & vbCrlf & _
    "Error number : " & Err.Number & vbCrlf & _
    "Error source : " & Err.Source
    MsgBox ErrDetail,vbCritical+vbSystemModal,Title
    Err.clear
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub RunAsAdmin()
    If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
        CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
        , chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & chr(34) & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```